# Vertex Texture Fetch in SM 2.0

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

According to this http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Texture_Fetch 
Said that it is enough that video card supports GL_ARB_texture_float to make texture fetch in a Vertex Shader.

Also, they said that ATI x300 does not support this, but:
http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/MOBILITY%20RADEON%20X300

So... does SM 2.0 video cards support VTF ? If yes, but not all, which one not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shader Model 2.0 is such a vague term. Each vendor had their own variation on Shader Model 2.0 and the differences really were not resolved until Shader Model 3.0 was standardized; thus you had SM2a, SM2b and SM2c.

Vertex texture fetches are actually a Shader Model 3.0 feature. And even then, not all hardware that claimed to be SM3 compliant supported them. For instance, anything based on the ATI Radeon x1000 ([R500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_R500)) architecture lacks said functionality.

In fact, the hardware you mentioned is actually based on the [R300](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_R300) architecture. This was the same class of hardware as the Radeon 9700 (first Shader Model 2.0 card on the market). So you definitely will not have vertex texture fetch support on a Mobility Radeon x300.